# Does ejb.jar and jboss-client.jar support java 11?

Tags: jboss7.x, ejb-3.1, java-11

Does below jar support java 11?

1. ejb.jar - javax.ejb API v.3.1 -Bundle-Vendor: GlassFish Community
2. jboss-client.jar - 7.1.1.Final - JBoss by Red Hat

Answer (score 1):

JBoss 7.1.1.Final doesn't support Java 8 so it's highly unlikely it would work with Java 11. WildFly 16 should work with Java 11 however.